# ST_SplitRight() in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, splitting

I am looking to split a shapefile via a line. I am interested only in the feature that lies to the right of the line; exactly what ST_SplitRight does **[here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=liblwgeom-4.0)**.

Do any of you know of a way to do this in PostGIS? After spending a couple hours searching I haven't been able to find any sort of solution.

Comment: How about comparing the coordinates of intersection with the coordinates of the first vertex to the left and to the right of it? Assuming you know how the CRS you use works, you might be able to choose the appropriate part of the linestring.